# Having an error with this.setState not being a function

Tags: react-native

I just learnt react native and is trying to learn how to implement swipe gesture from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures and I had an error about this.setstate not being a function. How can I resolve this issue? Is there something wrong with the way I tried to increase counter by 1?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Speaker from '../../img/flashcard/Speaker.png';
import GestureRecognizer, {swipeDirections} from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

//cards
import letter from '../../img/flashcard/c/letter.png';
import cow from '../../img/flashcard/c/cow.png';
import SwipeButton from 'rn-swipe-button';
//sounds

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    width: 345,
    height: 480,
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginTop: 34,
  },
  text: {fontSize: 30, fontFamily: 'Arial', color: 'grey'},
  speaker: {
    width: 86,
    height: 76,
    marginTop: 44,
  },
});

export default class flashcardC extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 1,
    imagecount: 10,
    imagesource: 'letter',
    soundsource: '',
  };

  updateImgsrc() {
    switch (this.state.imagesource) {
      case 1:
        return letter;
      case 2:
        return cow;
    }
  }
  onSwipeLeft(gestureState) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}));
    this.setState({imagesource: this.state.counter});

  }

  onSwipeRight(gestureState) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}));
    this.setState({imagesource: this.state.counter});

  }

  render() {
    const config = {
      velocityThreshold: 0.3,
      directionalOffsetThreshold: 80,
    };
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={{marginTop: 28, alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            {this.state.counter}/{this.state.imagecount}
          </Text>
          <GestureRecognizer
            onSwipeLeft={this.onSwipeLeft}
            onSwipeRight={this.onSwipeRight}
            config={config}>
            <Image src={this.updateImgsrc()} style={styles.card} />
          </GestureRecognizer>
          <Image source={Speaker} style={styles.speaker} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of the binding issues. Try to write all functions as arrow functions.

```
onSwipeLeft = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));
  this.setState({ imagesource: this.state.counter });
};

onSwipeRight = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));
  this.setState({ imagesource: this.state.counter });
};
```

Hope it helps you.